# How to traverse a linked list?

Tags: linked-list, nodes, traversal

The code for traversing kind of works. Not sure what I am doing wrong. It lets me add one node and when I try to add another the application crashes. As for the delete method I am not sure on how to even get that started. Any help will be appreciated

```
/* LinkList
     *  Anderson, Franceschi
     */

    /**
     * this class is a concrete implementation of the AbstractList.
     *
     * properties of this implementation are such that: - the list is singly linked
     * - data contained in the nodes is limited to integers - nodes are sorted in
     * ascending order of data - duplicate data is allowed - note that duplicate
     * data may cause inconsistent behavior in the Visualizer because the delete
     * method searches for the first instance of data. if a node besides the first
     * one is highlighted, the first one will still be deleted.
     */
    public class LinkList extends AbstractList
    {
      private Node head = null;

      public LinkList()
      {
        super(500, 400);
        v.drawList(head);
      }

      public LinkList(Node head)
      {
        super(500, 400); // set size for visualizer
        // set up the list
        head = head;

        animate(head);
      }

      public void insert(int i)
      {
        // ***** Student writes the body of this method *****

        // code the insert method of a linked list of ints
        // the int to insert in the linked list is i

        // we call the animate method inside the body of this method
        // as you traverse the list looking for the place to insert,
        // call animate as follows:

        //    animate(head, current);
        // where    head is the instance variable head of the linked list
        //          current is the node that you are visiting

        // you can start coding now

        // in order to improve the animation (this is optional):
        // just before inserting, i.e. connecting the nodes,
        // make the call

        //    animate(head, previous, Visualizer.ACTION_INSERT_AFTER);

        // where    head is the instance variable head of the linked list
        //          previous is the node (not null) after which to insert

        // if you are inserting at the beginning of the list,
        // just before inserting, make the call

        //    animate(head, head, Visualizer.ACTION_INSERT_BEFORE);

        // where    head is the instance variable head of the linked list
        //
        // Part 1 student code starts here:
    Node node = new Node(i);

    animate(head, head, Visualizer.ACTION_INSERT_BEFORE);
      if (head == null)
      {
        node.setNext(head);
        head = node;
      }



    else

      {
          node.setNext(head);
          head.setNext(node);

      }

      Node current = head;
      Node previous = null;

      animate(head, head, Visualizer.ACTION_INSERT_BEFORE);

       while (current.getNext() != null) {

                current = current.getNext();
            }
       current.setNext(previous);


     animate(head, previous, Visualizer.ACTION_INSERT_AFTER);







        // Part 1 student code ends here.

        numberNodes++;
        // call animate again to show the status of the list
        animate(head);
      }

      public boolean delete(int i)
      {
        // ***** Student writes the body of this method *****

        // code the delete method of a linked list of ints
        // the int to delete in the linked list is i
        // if deletion is successful, return true
        // otherwise, return false

        // we call the animate method inside the body of this method
        // as you traverse the list looking for the node to delete,
        // call animate as follows:

        //    animate(head, current);

        // where    head is the instance variable head of the linked list
        //          current is the node that you are visiting

        // you can start coding now

        // in order to improve the animation (this is optional):
        // just before deleting, i.e. connecting the nodes,
        // make the call

        //    animate(head, current, Visualizer.ACTION_DELETE);

        // where    head is the instance variable head of the linked list
        //          current is the node that you are deleting
        //
        // Part 2 student code starts here:





        // Part 2 student code ends here.

        // At this point, the item has been deleted.
        // Decrement the number of nodes:
        numberNodes--;
        // Call animate again to show the status of the list:
        animate(head);
        return true;
      }

      public int count()
      {
        int n = 0;
        Node current = head;
        while (current != null)
        {
          animate(head, current);
          n++;
          current = current.getNext();
        }
        return n;
      }

      public void traverse()
      {
        traversal = "";
        Node current = head;
        while (current != null)
        {
          animate(head, current);
          traversal += (current.getData() + "  ");
          current = current.getNext();
        }
        v.drawList(head);
      }

      public void clear()
      {
        head = null;
        v.drawList(head);
      }

      public void animate(Node h, Node nd)
      {
        v.drawList(h, nd);
        delay(1000);
      }

      public void animate(Node h)
      {
        v.drawList(h);
      }

      public void animate(Node h, Node nd, int mode)
      {
        v.drawList(h, nd, mode);
        delay(1000);
      }
    }
```

Comment: I would draw the pointers (arrows?) for this `node.setNext(head); head.setNext(node); ` :)

Comment: how would i go about doing that? --> ?